# Regular Expression - How do I capture before the first match?

Tags: php, regex

*Apparel & Fashion · United States · 10001+ employees · 5 billion Revenue*

*Non-profit Organization · Canada · 501-1000 employees*

Here are a couple examples above. I am trying to capture the industry ( ex. `Apparel & Fashion` or `Non-Profit Organization` )

I am trying to use the first · as a capture reference

This captures everything before the last dot (.+)\s·

But i want to capture everything before the first dot. How do I do this? Sorry that this is a basic question.

Comment: This is a basic question ... and it's  also a very good question.  SUGGESTION: consider using the PHP string functions strpos() and substr() instead of a regex, as Michał Turczyn proposed.  If you want to use a regex, then be sure to use an on-line tool to "evaluate" your expressions, such as https://www.regextester.com/ or https://regex101.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture everything that is NOT the `·`.  This allows you to use `preg_match_all` if needed to get all of the parts delimited by `·`:

`([^·]+)`

You can add the beginning anchor to only get the first one, but probably not needed:

`^([^·]+)`

However in PHP just:

```
$result = explode('·', $text)[0];
```

Or to get all:

```
$results = explode('·', $text)[0];
echo $results[0];
echo $results[1];
//etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use non-greedy regexp. (.+?)·

Comment: This is my first thought as well. There are many solutions but your question pertains to regex and `.+` will capture everything

Answer (score 1):

No need for regular expressions at all, see this code:

```
$position = strpos($string, "·", 5);  
$string = substr ( $string , 0, $position - 2 );
```

Where `$string` is the string to parse